# Fold Expression in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

I'm reading "C++17 - The Complete Guide" book and I came across the example on page 107 and 108 regarding fold expression in C++17:

```
template<typename First, typename... Args>
void print(First first, const Args&... args)
{
    std::cout << first;
    auto outWithSpace = [](const auto& arg)
    {
        std::cout << " " << arg;
    };
    (..., outWithSpace(args));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Is there any reason that the author couldn't do this as follows (without separating the first argument from the rest and apart from an extra printed space!):

```
template<typename... Types>
void print(Types const&... args)
{
    ([](const auto& x){ std::cout << x << " "; }(args), ...);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question? Yours prints an extra space.

Comment: @Barry, just wanted to make sure I'm not missing the point of the book example :)

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already figured out, the author could not have done as you suggest because that would leave an additional space…

What the author *could* have done though, would be something like

```cpp
template<typename First, typename... Args>
void print(First first, const Args&... args)
{
    ((std::cout << first), ..., (std::cout << ' ' << args)) << '\n';
}
```

or, rather

```cpp
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
std::ostream& print(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    return ((std::cout << std::forward<Arg>(arg)), ..., (std::cout << ' ' << std::forward<Args>(args))) << '\n';
}
```

live example [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:15),source:'%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Arg,+typename...+Args%3E%0Astd::ostream%26+print(Arg%26%26+arg,+Args%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++return+((std::cout+%3C%3C+std::forward%3CArg%3E(arg)),+...,+(std::cout+%3C%3C+!'+!'+%3C%3C+std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)))+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++print(1,+2,+3,+4)%3B%0A++++print(%22Hello%22,+%22World!!%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:73.7282397314806,l:'4',m:41.39482564679415,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:58.60517435320585,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:73.7282397314806,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:26.271760268519394,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Answer (score 0):

Plainly the *readable* way to write this is

```
template<typename... Types>
void print(Types const&... args)
{
    std::size_t n = 0;
    (std::cout << " " + !n++ << args), ...);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(with `std::forward` to taste).  The temptation to do this sort of nonsense (which could use `bool first` if C++17 hadn’t killed that *wonderful* feature) is the motivation for the `template for` feature planned for C++23.

Comment: @Barry i think he means arithmetic on `bool`

Comment: @RichardHodges: With tongue in cheek (like the answer), yes: for weird cases like this (and code golfing), post-increment (“has this been set already?”) and decrement (toggle) on `bool` were useful shorthands but far too obscure.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're having fun times with friends

```
template<typename First, typename... Args>`
void print(First&& first, Args&&... args)
{
    auto emit = [](auto&&...x) { ((std::cout << x), ...); };

    (emit(first), ..., emit(' ', args)), emit('\n');
}
```

:)

Answer (score -1):

No, it's just a question of aesthetics. No more reason.